# how to access custom attributes via rest api?

Tags: rest, intershop

I want to get custom Attributes from products via rest. I can't find the URL for the command.

This command works for links: /products/123456/links

Any idea how to Access the custom Attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the parameter "attrs" to specify the attributes you like:

http://hostname/INTERSHOP/rest/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS-Site/-/products/1YLEDTVSUP?attrs=YourAttributeName

See:
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/25167N